# Write into temp table from two alternate sql statements

Tags: sql, insert, temp-tables

I want to write the output of two queries into a table based on a condition. I have this piece of query but does not work. Please advise.

```
DECLARE @promptflag varchar(1) = 'N'; 
DECLARE @pool varchar(10) = 'PJMRTO';


IF Object_id('tempdb..#pnode') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #pnode;

select
    case when @promptflag='Y' then 
    (select distinct YES_PNODE from PRICE_NODES where ISO = @pool and Biddable='Y')
        when @promptflag='N' then
    (select distinct YES_PNODE from PRICE_NODES where ISO = @pool and Biddable='Y' and NonPrompt_Node='Y')
    end
```

INTO #pnode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is more like this:

```
select distinct YES_PNODE
into #pnode 
from PRICE_NODES
where ISO = @pool and Biddable = 'Y' and
      (@promptflag = 'Y' or  NonPrompt_Node = 'Y');
```

The `or` expression is just a shortening of your query logic.

Comment: Gordon, did you not have to put 'and' before open parenthesis?